# onClick not working when I attempt to change value of variable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onclick, event-listener

In React, I'm attempting to change the display of 2 elements when certain buttons are clicked on. I either want the title displayed, or an input to edit the title. My title div has a className of a variable named 'titleDisplay' with the value of 'isDisplayed'. I have a function set up to switch it to 'notDisplayed'

```
let titleDisplay = 'isDisplayed';
let editDisplay = 'notDisplayed';
const editDisplayed = () => {
        editDisplay = 'isDisplayed'
        titleDisplay = 'notDisplayed'
    }
```

```
<button onClick={editDisplayed} id="edit-btn">EDIT</button>
```

```
<div className={titleDisplay}>
   <h2 className='indieNotebookTitle'>{notebook?.title}</h2>
</div>
```

```
.isDisplayed {
    display: block;
}

.notDisplayed {
    display: none;
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong since onClick has been working with functions up until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React will only re-render a component in response to a state change. Reassigning a variable, by itself, almost never has any side-effects, unless the variable is used later. Your reassignment of `editDisplay` would only be visible to other functions within the same component binding (a very unusual occurrence to see in React, and usually an indicator of a logic problem).

You need to make the variables you try to change stateful instead. Also, consider using a boolean value rather than a string value. You may be able to use only a single state value instead, to toggle between the title and the edit.

```
const [editingTitle, setEditingTitle] = useState(false);
<button onClick={() => setEditingTitle(false)} id="edit-btn">EDIT</button>
```

```
<div className={editingTitle ? 'isDisplayed' : 'notDisplayed'}>
   <h2 className='indieNotebookTitle'>{notebook?.title}</h2>
</div>
```